# CakePHP - Add attribute to table rows using Html helper

Tags: cakephp

When building a table using `HtmlHelper`, is there any way to add an attribute such as an ID to all `<tr>` rows?

e.g. This is a simplified version of my current `<tbody>` code:

```
foreach ($subjects as $subject) {               
    echo $this->Html->tableCells(
        array(
            $subject['Subject']['id'],
            $subject['Subject']['name']
        ),
        array('class' => 'odd'), null, true
    );
}
```

I want to have the table come out something like:

```
<tr id="subj-34"><td ...
<tr id="subj-263"><td ...
<tr id="subj-11"><td ...
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to add a different id to each generated `<tr>`?

Comment: Yes.  It would probably be the subject ID, like `id="subj-37"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took me while to realize this was a simpler case than I first thought. You can just add the id attribute to the second and third parameters (so that it applies to both even and odd rows).

```
foreach ($subjects as $subject) {               
    echo $this->Html->tableCells(
        array(
            $subject['Subject']['id'],
            $subject['Subject']['name']
        ),
        array('class' => 'odd', 'id' = > 'subj-'.$subject['Subject']['id']), 
        array('id' = > 'subj-'.$subject['Subject']['id']), 
        true
    );
}
```

Comment: I had hoped there was a cleaner way to do it, but yeah I couldn't find any way to do it other than this.  Thanks.